# Changing channel from unbuffered to buffered prevents goroutine from running

Tags: go, select, concurrency, goroutine, channel

Here is an exercise using channels and select in a goroutine.  If the disconnect channel is changed to a buffered channel the goroutine doesn't run at all.

Why does changing from an unbuffered to a buffered channel prevent running the goroutine?

```
func SelectDemo(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {

    messageCh := make(chan int, 10)
    disconnectCh := make(chan struct{})
    //  go routine won't run if channel is buffered
    //disconnectCh := make(chan struct{}, 1)

    defer close(messageCh)
    defer close(disconnectCh)
    go func() {
        fmt.Println("  goroutine")
        wg.Add(1)
        for {
            select {
            case v := <-messageCh:
                fmt.Println(v)
            case <-disconnectCh:
                fmt.Println("  disconnectCh")
                //  empty the buffered channel before exiting
                for {
                    select {
                    case v := <-messageCh:
                        fmt.Println(v)
                    default:
                        fmt.Println("  disconnection, return")
                        wg.Done()
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }()

    fmt.Println("Sending ints")
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        messageCh <- i
    }

    fmt.Println("Sending done")
    disconnectCh <- struct{}{}
}
```

Here's the code to call the function from main.  I use the wait group to assure that the goroutine completes before the program exits:

```
wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
ch09.SelectDemo(&wg)
wg.Wait()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code logic has many flaws - some of them are:
1- Since the `messageCh` is buffered, this code is not blocking:

```
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        messageCh <- i
    }
```

so the next code is in the fast path to run:

```
disconnectCh <- struct{}{}
```

if you make the `disconnectCh` buffered, this line runs without **blocking** too, and the `SelectDemo` function **may exit** befor running the `wg.Add(1)`.

So: You must put:

```
wg.Add(1)
```

before

```
go func() {
```

2- Even with `wg.Add(1)` before `go func() {`   [code](https://go.dev/play/p/NxjwKGZD2sT) -
you have:

```
    defer close(messageCh)
    defer close(disconnectCh)
```

which will **close** both channels at `SelectDemo` function return
And this `select` is a random selection since both channels are ready:

```
fmt.Println("  goroutine")
        for {
            select {
            case v := <-messageCh:
                fmt.Println(v)
            case <-disconnectCh:
```

and it is **highly likely** that the second select:

```
                for {
                    select {
                    case v := <-messageCh:
                        fmt.Println(v)
                    default:
                        fmt.Println("  disconnection, return")
                        wg.Done()
                        return
                    }
                }
```

will run forever since the `messageCh` is closed, returning `0` forever after channel data read:

```
case v := <-messageCh:
    fmt.Println(v)
```

Comment: @DeanSchulze, to fix the infinitely looping goroutine remove the disconnectCh entirely and replace the for-select construct with a [for-range loop](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/4) over messageCh. Closing this channel breaks the range loop and is the only signal the goroutine needs to know that the sender is done.

Answer (score -1):

Program execution is fast

Visit URL: https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup.Add

Note that calls with a positive delta that occur when the counter is zero must happen before a Wait. Calls with a negative delta, or calls with a positive delta that start when the counter is greater than zero, may happen at any time. **Typically this means the calls to Add should execute before the statement creating the goroutine or other event to be waited for.** If a WaitGroup is reused to wait for several independent sets of events, new Add calls must happen after all previous Wait calls have returned. See the WaitGroup example.

```
func SelectDemo(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {

    messageCh := make(chan int, 10)
    disconnectCh := make(chan struct{}, 1)
    //  go routine won't run if channel is buffered
    //disconnectCh := make(chan struct{}, 1)

    wg.Add(1)

    defer close(messageCh)
    defer close(disconnectCh)
    go func() {
        fmt.Println("  goroutine")
        for {
            select {
            case v := <-messageCh:
                fmt.Println(v)
            case <-disconnectCh:
                fmt.Println("  disconnectCh")
                //  empty the buffered channel before exiting

                fmt.Println("  disconnection, return")
                wg.Done()
                return
            }
        }
    }()

    fmt.Println("Sending ints")
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        messageCh <- i
    }

    //Delay sending exit signal
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)

    fmt.Println("Sending done")
    disconnectCh <- struct{}{}
}
```

I modified your code

try again!!!

Comment: The time.Sleep() prevents multiple case statements within the select from becoming valid simultaneously which is the condition this code illustrates.